# Shelving in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs

I can't find shelving option. Currently I'm using Visual Studio 2010 for which I've been asked to use Shelving and Unshelving, but I can't seem to find where the shelve option in Visual Studio 2010 is.

I right clicked my file in Solution Explorer, I seem to have everything Build, Rebuild, Clean etc., options but no "Shelve Pending Changes" option. Do I need to install some plugin?

Answer (score 7):

It's in your pending changes view:

Top level menu: View > Other Windows > Pending Changes

Then you'll have two buttons for both shelving and unshelving:

[image: shelve and unshelve buttons]

Comment: Thank you Yannick Meeus , it was a tricky one, but got it :)

Comment: Thank you Yannick. It's really confusing though.